# Probability of choosing 6 from 49 where no numbers are next to each other

Tags: probability

What is a probability that when we choose 6 numbers form 1 to 49, we won't get adjacent numbers. In another we can't get a pair from those choosen 6 numbers whose difference equals 1.

What i have tried:

Well ${49 \choose 6}$ is a number of ways in which we can choose 6 from 49.

We have got $49-1=48$ adjacent pairs of numbers from 1 to 49.

We can choose pair of numbers from (1 to 49) in $49 \choose 2$ ways.

So probability that a two numbers choosen from 1 to 49 are adjacent is:

$\frac{48}{49 \choose 2} = \frac{2}{49}$

So probability that 2 choosen numbers won't be adjacent is $\frac{47}{49}$

From 6 numbers i can make:

${6 \choose 2}$ = 15 pairs.

Till now everything i have written is true.

And now something that i have made up but i am not sure about.

So is probability that i am trying to calculate equal ${\frac{47}{49}}^{15}$

Comment: The last step can not be done, because the probabilities that the 15 pairs are adjacent are not independent.

Comment: In the last step, if it were correct, you would want $1-\left(\frac {47}{49}\right)^{15}$ for the question you ask.  This would be correct if the probabilities were independent and very close if $\frac {47}{49}$ were very close to $1$ (if you had lots more than $49$ numbers)

Comment: Ok so is there any way to join somehow probability of those independent pairs with those 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, how many sets of $k$  numbers $x_j$ from $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$
 with $x_1<x_2<\cdots <x_k$
have no consecutive values? We can use the bijection
$$(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k)\quad \longleftrightarrow \quad  (x_1,x_2-1,\dots, x_k-(k-1))$$
where $x_j-(j-1)$'s are distinct values from $\{1,2,\dots,  n-(k-1)\}$.
 The number of different ways  is therefore  ${n-k+1\choose k}$.

For Lotto 6-49 the answer is ${44\choose 6}$,
so the required probability is ${{44\choose 6}/ {49\choose 6}}=.5048.$